# Solve for $x$: $(x+0.6)^2 = 1.4x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am very terrible at some aspects of algebra and I would like to ask how to solve this problem (It's actually only a small part of a larger physics problem). I've looked up the laws of exponents and from what I can tell I cannot easily seperate the $x$ from the $0.6$. At this point I am quite confused and would appreciate a step by step approach:

> Solve for $x$:
>
> $$(x+0.6)^2 = 1.4x^2$$

Comment: By the way, I know the answer is x=3.275 but I'm not sure how to get it.

Comment: Both responses are useful, although amWhy's answer resulted in a more direct and quick approach. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by taking the square root of each side of the equation.
$$\sqrt{(x + 0.6)^2} = \sqrt{1.4x^2} =(x+0.6) = \sqrt{1.4}x$$

Then solve for $x$, and evaluate:

$$(\sqrt{1.4} - 1)x = 0.6 \implies x = \dfrac{0.6}{\sqrt{1.4} - 1} \approx 3.275$$

Note that this method gives you only the positive solution for $x$ (there is also a negative solution), but I suspect, given the solution you already have, is the only one applicable given the physic's context of the problem.

---

The alternative (and mathematically more sound) approach is to expand the term on the left hand side, and solve for the resulting quadratic equation:

$$
\begin{align}
(x+0.6)^2 &= 1.4x^2\\ \\
x^2+1.2x+0.36 &=1.4x^2\\ \\
-0.4x^2+1.2x+0.36&=0 
\end{align}
$$

Now, you can use the [***quadratic formula***](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticFormula.html) to obtain both the positive solution and the negative solution: $x \approx -0.275$ and $x\approx 3.275$.

Comment: But remember the square root may be negative on one or both sides

Comment: @Ross Yes, I commented on that following the method used. I assumed, given the solution he was working with, that the negative root/solution did not apply (physics context). Generally, in a strictly algebra-precal context, I'd have suggested solving the quadratic to find both real solutions, one of which is, indeed, negative.

Answer (score 6):

$$(x+0.6)^2 = 1.4x^2$$
$$x^2+1.2x+0.36=1.4x^2$$
$$-0.4x^2+1.2x+0.36=0$$

Now use the ABC-formula to solve for x.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+0,6)^{2}=1,4x^2$$
$$x^2+1,2x+0,36=1,4x^2$$
$$0,4x^2-1,2x-0,36=0$$
$$0,4(x^2-3x-9)=0$$
$$x^2-3x-9=0$$

then we get $x=\frac{3+3\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or $x=\frac{3-3\sqrt{5}}{2}$

i think it can be an answer without calculate the approximation value

Comment: Careful. 0.4 * 9 is not 0.36

Answer (score 0):

$(x+0.6)^2 = 1.4x^2$ is not really a quadratic equation because $a^2=b^2$ iff $a=\pm b$, since $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Hence from $(x+0.6)^2 = 1.4x^2$ we get $x+0.6 = \pm \sqrt{1.4}\,x$ and so $x=0.6/(1\pm\sqrt{1.4})$.